# How to connect discrete points and make them become continuous curve?

Tags: visualization, plotting

Given that I have two variables $\theta,t$, for the varible $t$, $\theta$ always owns several values. Namely, $$\{t,\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3,\theta_4...\}$$
where $t$ in the interval$[0,1]$ and $\theta$ in the interval$[0,2\pi]$

**My sample data**

```
originalData=
{{0,2.99939,6.16435},{0.010101,3.03635,6.19686},{0.020202,3.07484,6.22946}, 
 {0.030303,3.11493,6.26213},{0.040404,0.011674,3.15666}, 
 {0.0505051,0.0444528,3.20004},{0.0606061,0.0772844,3.24504},
 {0.0707071,0.110179,3.29156},{0.0808081,0.143159,3.33945},
 {0.0909091,0.176258,3.38851},{0.10101,0.209527,3.43847},{0.111111,0.243035,3.48904},
 {0.121212,0.276879,3.53988},{0.131313,0.311186,3.59066},{0.141414,0.346126,3.64109},
 {0.151515,0.381932,3.69088},{0.161616,0.418919,3.73981},{0.171717,0.457536,3.78768},
 {0.181818,0.498437,3.83436},{0.191919,0.54263,3.87976},{0.20202,0.591793,3.92382},
 {0.212121,0.649054,3.96653},{0.222222,0.7215,4.00787},
 {0.232323,1.79066,1.4441,0.834008,4.0479},{0.242424,2.04691,4.08662},
 {0.252525,2.17701,4.12412},{0.262626,2.27155,4.16044},
 {0.272727,2.3473,4.19565},{0.282828,2.41109,4.22982},{0.292929,2.46649,4.26302},
 {0.30303,2.51566,4.29532},{0.313131,2.56,4.3268},{0.323232,2.60048,4.35752},
 {0.333333,2.63783,4.38756},{0.343434,2.67258,4.41699},{0.353535,2.70514,4.44588},
 {0.363636,2.73583,4.47429},{0.373737,2.76491,4.5023},{0.383838,2.79261,4.52997},
 {0.393939,2.81908,4.55739},{0.40404,2.84448,4.58461},{0.414141,2.86894,4.61171},
 {0.424242,2.89255,4.63878},{0.434343,2.91541,4.66589},{0.444444,2.9376,4.69313}, 
 {0.454545,2.95918,4.7206},{0.464646,2.9802,4.74841},{0.474747,3.00073,4.77666},
 {0.484848,3.02081,4.8055},{0.494949,3.04048,4.83508},{0.505051,3.05977,4.86559},
 {0.515152,3.07872,4.89726},{0.525253,3.09736,4.93036},
 {0.535354,3.1157,0.308209,0.214389,4.96529},
 {0.545455,3.13379,0.428984,0.0480804,5.0025},
 {0.555556,0.485269,6.22645,5.04269,3.15163},  
 {0.565657,0.526307,6.13285,5.08687,3.16925},
 {0.575758,0.55954,6.0414,5.13667,3.18666},
 {0.585859,0.587877,5.94624,5.19502,3.20387},
 {0.59596,0.612803,5.83937,5.26845,3.22092},
 {0.606061,0.635191,5.69654,5.38031,3.2378},{0.616162,0.655606,3.25452},
 {0.626263,0.674433,3.27111},{0.636364,0.691951,3.28758},{0.646465,0.708367,3.30392},
 {0.656566,0.72384,3.32015},{0.666667,0.738494,3.33628},{0.676768,0.75243,3.35231},
 {0.686869,0.765729,3.36826},{0.69697,0.778458,3.38412},{0.707071,0.790675,3.3999},
 {0.717172,0.802427,3.41561},{0.727273,0.813756,3.43125},{0.737374,0.824695,3.44683},
 {0.747475,0.835277,3.46235},{0.757576,0.845527,3.4778},{0.767677,0.85547,3.4932},
 {0.777778,0.865127,3.50855},{0.787879,0.874516,3.52384},{0.79798,0.883655,3.53909},
 {0.808081,0.892558,3.55428},{0.818182,0.901239,3.56942},{0.828283,0.90971,3.58452},
 {0.838384,0.917984,3.59956},{0.848485,0.92607,3.61456},{0.858586,0.933978,3.6295},
 {0.868687,0.941717,3.64439},{0.878788,0.949295,3.65923},{0.888889,0.956718,3.67401},
 {0.89899,0.963995,3.68873},{0.909091,0.971132,3.70339},{0.919192,0.978135,3.71798},
 {0.929293,0.985008,3.73251},{0.939394,0.991759,3.74697},{0.949495,0.998391,3.76135},
 {0.959596,1.00491,3.77566},{0.969697,1.01132,3.78988},{0.979798,1.01762,3.80402},
 {0.989899,1.02382,3.81806},{1.,1.02993,3.83201}};
```

**My goal**

I would like to plot independent curves according these discrete points in one graphic.

**My trial**

Firstly, I visualize these discrete points and show them in one graphic:

```
 Data1 = Thread@{originalData[[All, 1]], originalData[[All, 2]]};
 Data2 = Thread@{originalData[[All, 1]], originalData[[All, 3]]};
 middle = Cases[originalData, {_, _, _, _, _}];
 Data3 = Thread@{middle[[All, 1]], middle[[All, 4]]};
 Data4 = Thread@{middle[[All, 1]], middle[[All, 5]]};
```

---

```
 Show[
  ListPlot[#1, PlotStyle -> {#2, PointSize[Small]}] & @@@
   (Thread@{{Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4}, {Red, Blue, Black, Green}}),
   AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}, ImageSize -> 700, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 7}},
   GridLines -> {{}, {0, 2 \[Pi]}}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[.02],
   GridLinesStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[1, 0, 1], Dashed],
   AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 15, Red, Italic, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica"] & /@ {"t", "\[Theta]"})]
```

> [image]

By the visualizstion of `ListPlot` and `Show`, I know that there are 4 part(Part 1,Part 2,Part 3,Part 4) subpictures in this graphic.

[image]

#### My question(difficulty)

1,Is it possible to connect the the disrete points of Part $i$.Namely, make the Part $i$ become a continuous curve?

2,Now I have no idea to solve this problem, so if possible, can someone give some **`suggestions (algorithm or hint)`**? Thanks in advance:-)

Comment: You could use `Nearest` or similar to stitch your point sets together. Other possibly (?) useful functions: `FindCurvePath` and `FindShortestTour`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Method 1**: `FindCurvePath` (as mentioned by Yves Klett). This method is simple, but unfortunately, there are small issues (as shown in plots), that the curves are not identified perfectly.

```
arrayData = 
  Flatten[Function[{lst}, {First @ lst, #} & /@ Rest[lst]] /@ 
    originalData, 1];

curvesPosition = FindCurvePath[arrayData];

ListPlot[curves = 
  arrayData[[curvesPosition[[#]]]] & /@ Range@Length@curvesPosition, 
 Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> None]
```

[image]

**Method 2**: Code to separate curves by hand:

The list `arrayData` converts `originalData` into the form {{t1, θ1}, {t2, θ2}, ...}. This form is easier for processing.

```
arrayData = 
  Flatten[Function[{lst}, {First @ lst, #} & /@ Rest[lst]] /@ 
    originalData, 1];
```

Because we plan to measure `EuclideanDistance` later, we first normalize the data. After splitting the data into segments, we shall restore the standard deviation.

```
SD = StandardDeviation[arrayData];
applySD = {#1/SD[[1]], #2/SD[[2]]} &;
restoreSD = {#1 * SD[[1]], #2 * SD[[2]]} &;

normData = applySD @@@ arrayData;
```

To avoid curves breaking in the middle, we shall need to find starting points of a a curve. The function `findStart` does this job. The best guess starting point `A` is the point such that the two nearest points to `A` (denoted by `B` and `C`) point to closest directions, i.e. ∠BAC is smallest. If the points are dense enough, ∠BAC should be close to 0 for starting points, and close to π for a point in the middle of a segment.

```
findStart[lst_]:= Module[{near1, near2, angle, best, bestAngle = Infinity},
    Do[
        If[Length @ lst <= 2, Return[lst[[1]]]];
        {near1, near2} = Nearest[lst, elem, 3][[2;;]]; (* exclude elem itself *)
        angle = VectorAngle[near1-elem, near2-elem];
        If[angle < bestAngle, best = elem; bestAngle = angle]
    , {elem, lst}];
    best]
```

The `moveStep` is the major function to do the work. `moreStep[{lst, new}]` acts as follows:

Find the nearest point to the last element of `new` in `lst`. If the point is near (there is a parameter to define near, 0.5 in the code), move the nearest point from lst to new. If the nearest point is too far away (i.e. not on the current segment), save the current segment and reset the `new` list.

Note that the list that the OP gives is ordered in `t`. If it is not the case, one should sort the list by t. Otherwise, a segment may be broken into two from the middle.

```
moveStep = Function[{input},Module[{elem,neighbor,lst,new},
    lst = First@input;
    new = Last@input;
    If[new=!={}, elem=new[[-1]], elem = findStart @ lst];
    neighbor=Nearest[lst,elem][[1]];
    If[EuclideanDistance[elem,neighbor]>0.5, 
        AppendTo[segments,new];
        {lst, {}}
        ,{DeleteCases[lst,neighbor], Append[new,neighbor]}]]];
```

Then we shall apply multiple steps using `Nest`. Each step moves one element. Thus the number of steps to nest is length of `arrayData`.

```
segments = {};
test = NestWhile[moveStep, {normData, {}}, #[[1]] =!= {} &];
AppendTo[segments, Last@test];
```

Restore standard derivation, and plot the result.

```
result = Apply[restoreSD, segments, {2}];

ListPlot[result, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer!I am reading this to understand your program!Thanks a lot:-)

Comment: Dear Yi Wang, I cannot understand the code `If[neighbor===elem, neighbor = Nearest[DeleteCases[lst, neighbor], elem][[1]]];`in the function `moveStep`. Could you explain it to me? In addition, I'd like to know that `why the data need be normalized`? Thanks !:-)

Comment: @ShutaoTang : After looking at the code again, I apologize that there were a few problems. (1) As you points out, this If[...] statement is confusing and not necessary. To keep things consistent, `DeleteCases[lst,neighbor]` is used for both cases at the end of `moveStep`. (2) I noted that in the previous version, "⊂" shaped curve cannot be identified nicely, because it cannot guess the start point of "⊂" shaped curve. I added `findStart` function to find starting point of a curve more carefully.

Comment: Also, it appears a bit stupid to use `Do` loop to find minimal value. `MinimalBy` should be the one to use. But considering that `MinimalBy` is a new function in version 10, I did not use it for compatibility reason. I believe there are some other bad practices as well because I am feeling that I am not writing functional code (with a similar experience to writing in C with a handy math library) when coding it up.

Comment: In the morning,@Yi Wang to understand the purpose of that code, I deleted that code(`If[]`) then I got a closely similar result.

Comment: The data is normalized because, otherwise, calculating `EuclideanDistance` in the vertical piece "|" and the horizontal piece "-" of a curve cannot give comparable result.

Comment: When I encoutered this problem a week ago firstly,@Yi Wang I didn't have any idea to deal with it. So I am very happy and honor to get your help. In addition, I am used writing functional programming in MMA, but the ***algorithm*** in your code is very significant and  it is worth studying：)

Comment: @ShutaoTang : Nice to hear that you like it :)

Comment: For speed improvement I would suggest precomputing `nf=Nearest[list]` (outside `moveStep`) and then using `nf[elem]` subsequently. I think it will be faster to pass the `NearestFunction` into the subroutine than to recompute it every time.

Comment: Another idea is that a point will "usually" have but two nearest neighbors. When it does not, the "crossings" can often be detected simply by deciding which pairs have similar one-sided directions (or just by taking non-adjacent points for each neighbor pair). This will need work in cases where two curves approach but do not cross, or when neighbors of a crossing also claim to have more than two neighbors. I would expect that numerical derivative approximations will be needed to sort out such cases.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau : Thanks a lot for the comments! (1) Note that `lst` is modified each time `moveStep` is called, at `DeleteCases[lst,neighbor]`. Thus I cannot pre-compute a list before calling `moveStep`. The performance of the code should be very bad. Luckily the list that the OP gives is not too large. For very large lists, we may need to reconsider the algorithm. (2) That's a good point! I haven't considered the crossing case. That would be similar to the case of searching for start point of the segment, by consider angles among nearest points.

Comment: Great work! I think the `findStart` function may need a small correction: the `If[Length @ lst <= 2, Return[lst[[1]]]];` statement should appear before the `Do` loop; otherwise the `Return` exits the `Do` loop but not the function itself.

Comment: @SimonRochester: Good point! I think you are right but I am a bit busy now and will test that later. (The code nevertheless still works. Probably that `If` is not necessary?)

Comment: It's only a problem if you happen to have one or two points left over after collecting all of the other segments. Then it throws an error, which is how I noticed it. So it's usually not necessary, but occasionally crucial...

Answer (score 13):

One can use the periodicity over $\theta$ and add one periodic copy of the data. In this case `FindCurvePath` works much better. I also add an interpolation of the result

```
arrayData = Flatten[Thread@{#, Join[{##2}, {##2} + 2 π]} & @@@ originalData, 1];
curvesPosition = FindCurvePath@arrayData;
{t, θ} = Interpolation@Transpose@{Range[0., 1, 1/(Length@# - 1)], #} & /@ 
      Transpose@arrayData[[#]] & /@ curvesPosition // Transpose;

ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Table[{t[[i]][ξ], θ[[i]][ξ]}, {i, Length@t}], {ξ, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 4 π}}]
```

[image: plot of data]

Let's select only full curves and plot them by $\bmod 2\pi$. Now we explicitly see that there are only two branches:

```
ParametricPlot[{{t[[1]][ξ], Mod[θ[[1]][ξ], 2 π]}, 
  {t[[2]][ξ], Mod[θ[[2]][ξ], 2 π]}}, {ξ, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 2 π}}]
```

[image: plot with two branches]